# IIS Express redirects to URL with some kind of session ID

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

Normally when I start my application, a browser window is opened with the URL

```
http://localhost:12345/
```

Since some change in some configuration, this gets redirected to

```
http://localhost:12345/(S(presumablySomeBase64EncodedValue))
```

Then, all the relative links like `home/index` become

```
http://localhost:12345/(S(presumablySomeBase64EncodedValue))/home/index
```

which produces `HTTP 501`s on the server

I have no idea what this is and how to get rid of it. I don't even know the name of this base-64 value. Is it a session ID?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your web.config file, add this:

```
<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

under system.web tag.